# Designated label not displaying countdown

Tags: swift, xcode, timer, countdown

I have a countdown implemented but currently the label assigned to display the value isn't showing the value at all. I've tried print(countdownLabel) to see if it is recording in which the label's properties are returned and not the countdown. Thanks in advance!

```
class CountdownViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var iconImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var countdownLabel: UILabel!

    //Countdown
    let futureDate: Date = {
        let future = DateComponents(
            year: 2021,
            month: 1,
            day: 06,
            hour: 09,
            minute: 32 ,
            second: 45
        )
        return Calendar.current.date(from: future)!

    }()

    var countdown: DateComponents {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: futureDate)
    }

    @objc func updateTime() {
        let countdown = self.countdown //only compute once per call
        let days = countdown.day!
        let hours = countdown.hour!
        let minutes = countdown.minute!
        let seconds = countdown.second!
        self.countdownLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", days, hours, minutes, seconds)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        func runCountdown() {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
        runCountdown()
        (print(countdown))
        (print(countdownLabel as Any))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem in your code is, you declared function `runCountdown()` inside another function `viewDidLoad()` but, you didn't call `runCountdown()` afterwards.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    func runCountdown() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    runCountdown()
    (print(countdown))
    (print(countdownLabel as Any))
}
```